# How can I read 32-bit binary numbers from a binary file in python?

Tags: python

I have data files which contain series of 32-bit binary "numbers."

I say "numbers" because the 32 1/0's define what type of data sensors were picking up, when they were, which sensor,etc; so the decimal value of the numbers is of no concern to me. In particular some (most) of the data will begin with possibly up to 5 zeros.

I simply need a way in python to read these files, get a list containing each 32-bit number, and then I'll need to mess around with it a little (delete some events) and rewrite it to a new file.

Can anyone help me with this? I've tried the following so far but the numbers which should be corresponding to the time data we encode seem to be impossible.

```
with open(lm_file, mode='rb') as file: 
    bytes_read = file.read(struct.calcsize("I"))
    while bytes_read:
        idList = struct.unpack("I", bytes_read)[0]
        idList=bin(idList)
        print(idList)
        bytes_read = file.read(struct.calcsize("=l"))
```

Output of hexdump:

```
00000000  80 0a 83 4d ba a5 80 0c  c0 00 7b 42 cb 90 0f 41  |...M......{B...A|
00000010  98 c9 9c 53 4c 15 35 52  d8 54 f7 0a 5d 87 16 4d  |...SL.5R.T..]..M|
00000020  89 6a 3f 04 f2 eb c4 4a  e2 37 e6 08 23 5e ca 06  |.j?....J.7..#^..|
```

Comment: Are you sure they are stored as little-endian?

Comment: I am positive they are little endian.

Comment: Please provide an example of data. Use `hexdump -Cv binary.bin | head -n 10` to get a hexdump.

Comment: @George I hope this is sufficient, -n 10 is too many characters for a comment

    `00000000  80 0a 83 4d ba a5 80 0c  c0 00 7b 42 cb 90   0f 41  |...M......{B...A|
00000010  98 c9 9c 53 4c 15 35 52  d8 54 f7 0a 5d 87 16 4d  |...SL.5R.T..]..M|
00000020  89 6a 3f 04 f2 eb c4 4a  e2 37 e6 08 23 5e ca 06  |.j?....J.7..#^..|`

Comment: @Karl can you put this in the question?  it's difficult to read in the comments

Comment: Done-- sorry I was having a lot of trouble making it readable-- good idea

Comment: the first 4 bytes (`80 0a 83 4d`) represent 1300433536 for me (LE/intel 4 byte int) which would be 2011-03-18T07:32:16 if you're treating it as  unix timestamp.  is that anywhere close to what you're expecting?

Comment: Perhaps try forcing struct to interpret the bytes read as little endian? i.e. `struct.unpack("<I", bytes_read)`